# How to find files bigger then some size, and sort them by last modification date?

Tags: bash, find

I need to write script which write down each files in selected catalog, which are bigger then some size. Also I need to sort them by size, name and last modification date.

So I have made the first two cases:

**Sort by size**

```
RESULTS=`find $CATALOG -size +$SIZE | sort -n -r | sed 's_.*/__'`
```

**Sort by name**

```
RESULTS=`find $CATALOG -size +$SIZE | sed 's_.*/__' | sort -n `
```

But I have no idea how to sort results by last modification date.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Also see [How can I find files that are bigger/smaller than x bytes?](http://superuser.com/q/204564/173513) on Super User.

Comment: I actually found an answer to a question I was going to ask in this very question (finding files over a certain size) - thank you :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One of the best approaches, provided you don't have too many files, is to use `ls` to do the sorting itself.

Sort by name and print one file per line:

```
find $CATALOG -size +$SIZE -exec ls -1 {} +
```

Sort by size and print one file per line:

```
find $CATALOG -size +$SIZE -exec ls -S1 {} +
```

Sort by modification time and print one file per line:

```
find $CATALOG -size +$SIZE -exec ls -t1 {} +
```

You can also play with the `ls` switches: Sort by modification time (small first) with long listing format, with human-readable sizes:

```
find $CATALOG -size +$SIZE -exec ls -hlrt {} +
```

Oh, you might want to only `find` the files (and ignore the directories):

```
find $CATALOG -size +$SIZE -type f -exec ls -hlrt {} +
```

Finally, some remarks: Avoid capitalized variable names in bash (it's considered bad practice) and avoid back ticks, use `$(...)` instead. E.g.,

```
results=$(find "$catalog" -size +$size -type f -exec ls -1rt {} +)
```

Also, you probably don't want to put all the results in a string like the previous line. You probably want to put the results in an array. In that case, use `mapfile` like this:

```
mapfile -t results < <(find "$catalog" -size +$size -type f -exec ls -1rt {} +)
```

Comment: Thanks, very helpful and exhaustive answer.

Comment: I always wonder how it could be cool if locate command could be used instead of find. As a rule of thumb it works much faster than find. Unfortunately it doesn't have "-exec" option(

Answer (score 1):

Try `xargs` (do whatever, treating STDIN as a list of arguments) and the `-t` and `-r` flags to `ls`. 
i.e. something like this:

```
find $CATALOG -size +$SIZE | xargs ls -ltr
```

That will give you the files sorted by last modification date.

Sorting by multiple attributes at once is going to be really awkward to do with shell utilities and pipes though — I think you'll need to use a scripting language (ruby, perl, php, whatever), unless your shell fu is strong.